# The last non zero digit of N!

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Surfing the web, I found a claim that the last non zero digit of $(5A+B)!$, where $A, B \in \mathbb Z^+$ and $0 \le B < 5$ is equal to the last non zero digit of $2^A \cdot A! B!$, but I could not find a proof.

So I came up with the proof below. How does it look?

**Theorem:** The last non zero digit of $(5A)!$ is equal to the last nonzero digit of $2^A \cdot A!$.

**PROOF.**

Write out the product $(5A)!$ in $A$ rows of $5$ consecutive digits:

$\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
   1 &\cdot &  2 &\cdot &  3 &\cdot &  4 &\cdot &  5 & \cdot \\
   6 &\cdot &  7 &\cdot &  8 &\cdot &  9 &\cdot &  10 & \cdot \\
   11 &\cdot &  12 &\cdot &  13 &\cdot & 14 &\cdot &  15 & \cdot \\
   16 &\cdot &  17 &\cdot &  18 &\cdot &  19 &\cdot &  20 & \cdot \\
     &&&&\vdots \\
   (5A-4) &\cdot & (5A-3) &\cdot & (5A-2) &\cdot & (5A-1) &\cdot & 5A
\end{array} \tag 1 $

Each row of $(1)$ is of the form

$$(10n+1)(10n+2)(10n+3)(10n+4)(10n+5)$$
$$\text{or}$$
$$(10n+6)(10n+7)(10n+8)(10n+9)(10n+10)$$

Factoring out two $2s$ and a $5$, we find that

\begin{array}{l}
   (10n+1)(10n+2)(10n+3)(10n+4)(10n+5) \\
   = 10 \cdot [2(10n+1)(5n+1)(10n+3)(5n+2)] \cdot (2n+1)
\end{array}

\begin{array}{l}
   (10n+6)(10n+7)(10n+8)(10n+9)(10n+10) \\
   = 10 \cdot [2(5n+3)(10n+7)(5n+4)(10n+9)] \cdot (2n+2)
\end{array}

Since $2(5n+1)(5n+2) \equiv 2(5n+3)(5n+4) \equiv 4 \pmod{10}$, then
$$2(10n+1)(5n+1)(10n+3)(5n+2) \equiv  2 \pmod{10}$$
and
$$2(5n+3)(10n+7)(5n+4)(10n+9) \equiv 2 \pmod{10}$$

So we can rewrite the product $(1)$ to show that the last non zero digit of $5A!$ is equal to the last non zero digit of

$\begin{array}{ccccc}
   10 & \cdot & 2 & \cdot & 1 & \cdot \\
   10 & \cdot & 2 & \cdot & 2 & \cdot \\
   10 & \cdot & 2 & \cdot & 3 & \cdot \\
   && \vdots \\
   10 & \cdot & 2 & \cdot & A \\
\end{array} \tag 2 $

We can ignore the $10s$ since they have no effect on the value of the last non zero digit. It follows that the last non zero digit of $(5A)!$ is equal to the last non zero digit of $2^A \cdot A!$.

The following lemma is an immediate consequence of the above theorem.

**Lemma.** Express the positive integer $N$ as $N=5A+B$ where $0 \le B < 5$. Then the last nonzero digit of $N!$ is equal to the last non zero digit of 
$2^A \cdot A! B!$.

Comment: I think it's clear you're talking about $(5A)!$ not $5\cdot A!$ but it's less clear if you are referring to $(2^AA)!$ or $2^A\cdot A!$. Working through your question I would say the latter but you might like to update for clarity, since you are taking different interpretations to juxtaposition in these cases.